# Python пропуск куска кода по условию

Tags: python

Как в Python проверить условие и перейти к определенному массиву кода в программе при соблюдении/несоблюдении заданного условия.

Может есть какой-нибудь модуль, который позволяет выставить в коде маркер, к которому необходимо перейти интерпретатору, если условие соблюдено/несоблюдено.

Прошу без отфутболивания к манам и простейших "подсказок", а-ля засунь это всё в if...

Comment: То есть вы хотите `goto` для `python`? Есть билиотека https://github.com/snoack/python-goto, но это извращение.

Comment: И всё-таки я рекомендую вам не искать аналог goto, а изучить нормальные подходы к построению программы. Как только программа становится чуть сложнее примитивного линейного скрипта и появляется потребность переходить от одной части кода к другой нужно начинать структурировать код с помощью функций. Если у вас есть функции - вы можете по условию вызвать одну из них, и это ничуть не хуже использования перехода к метке, а лучше - очень многим. Сначала может быть непривычно, но если вы хотите программировать, а не просто писать короткие линейные скрипты, нужно использовать правильный подход.

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример, вам подскажут решение. Александр прав.

Comment: Спасибо за советы и ваше время, ребята :) Жаль, что так нельзя сделать в Python пока что. Но думаю, когда я буду лучше разбираться в этом, всё получиться. Еще раз спасибо и всем хорошего кода:)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
a, b = random.randint(1, 2), random.randint(1, 2)

class Goto:
    @staticmethod
    def label1():
        r = a + b
        print(r)
        return r

    @staticmethod
    def label2():
        r = Goto.label1() - 1
        print(r)

if a > b:
    Goto.label1()
else:
    Goto.label2()
```

Comment: К сожалению не получится эти методы сильно межу собой зациклить (в отличие от настоящего goto) - стека не хватит.

Comment: Спасибо за вами потраченное время и оказанную поддержку, ребята :) Я пока не разбираюсь в Python, но буду разбираться. Если простого какого-то решения (функции или там чего-то еще) нет, то проще мне оставить в покое эту тему и просто пока учиться дальше.